# What type of coordinates are these and how to transform them to standard WGS84 (EPSG:4326)?

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg, colombia

I have the coordinates :

North = 861597.4129 , East = 1063313.808

All I know is that they should belong somewhere in the city of Cali, Colombia. I have tried different Colombian EPSG codes but I still do not know which format they are in.

Answer (score 2):

I get similar coordinates if I use 21896, Bogota 1975 / Colombia West Zone or 6249, MAGNA-SIRGAS / Cali urban grid or 3115, MAGNA-SIRGAS / Colombia West zone.

When I check the actual point, all three coordinate reference systems place the point in the same relative location, are very close and appear to be on a hillside (mountainside?) in a southern part of the city. I can't tell you for certain which one is the correct coordinate reference system.

Comment: Ok that's great. I have not been able to plot them in QGIS or anywhere, how did you plot the points? And why I cannot transform the coordinates anywhere? For example I tried to transform 6249 in https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=4326&t_srs=6249 without results

Comment: I work at Esri on coordinate systems so I used ArcMap. Added a topographic basemap and then set the data frame ("map") coordinate reference system to ones suitable for Cali. As to why it didn't work--I don't know! Maybe whatever epsg.io is using for conversions doesn't support the Colombia urban grid yet.